# SQL: deleting data where parent doesn't exist

Tags: sql

I have a hierarchical table 'pages', with 'id' and 'id_parent' fields. Thanks to some crappy old code there are still a lot of rows without a parent. I want to delete these rows. Is this possible using only SQL?

Answer (score 5):

yes.  This is simple and unoptimized, (and assumes that the parent is no longer in existence) but it would give you a place to start

```
DELETE FROM Pages WHERE Id_Parent NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM PagesParent);
```

Based on the comment, it appears that this is a self-referencing table.  Basically, ID_Parent of Pages is linked to the ID of Pages.

Therefore you need to torture TSQL a bit. **NOTE:** I work with SQL SERVER and am not certain if this is standard SQL and will work in other RDBMS. That said, something along these lines should get what you're after.

```
WITH t(ID, ID_Parent) AS
(
    SELECT ID,ID_Parent from Pages where id = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT st.ID, st.ID_Parent FROM Pages st
       INNER JOIN  t ON st.ID_Parent = t.id
)
DELETE PAGES
       FROM Pages s
            LEFT JOIN t ON s.ID = t.ID
       WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried

DELETE FROM pages WHERE id != 1 AND id_parent NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pages)

But i get "You can't specify target table 'pages' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @tape2: The table specified in the subquery needs to be the parent table. Typo?

Comment: @Jon - not necessarily.  We're making the assumption that there are 2 distinct tables here, but from his comment that's not necessarily the case....

Comment: @Stephen: Actually, come to think of it after re-reading the question, I think there's only a single table.

Comment: I up voted because this helped me with another problem that was similar. I needed to update an IsCurrentVersion Bit for objects that had parents with IsCurrentVersion set to false. hacked to be Update Child set IsCurrentVersion = 0 where Child.ParentId in (select Id from Parent where IsCurrentVersion = 0) Awesome! saved me lots of headache!

Comment: Also, to me it seems more likely that there were two tables. If not, where would the parent Ids that are valid be coming from? Unless they have a list of valid parent Ids that they want to check against stored somewhere externally(txt,csv,etc etc) which they wish to parse in, I would guess it was 2 tables.

Comment: George - Glad it helped you--but it's possible that you can have a self-referencing table. I.e. think about a table of Employees. Now, each Employee will have a Manager, and a Manager is also an employee with another Employee as its Manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
--DELETE 
FROM myTable
WHERE id_parent IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT id
--DELETE 
FROM myTable
WHERE id_parent IS NOT IN (SELECT id FROM myTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it that way:

```
delete P 
from Pages P 
left join PagesParent Parent
   on Parent.Id_Parent=P.Id_Parent
where Parent.Id_Parent is null -- This tells you that the row doesn't exists in the table PagesParent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
DELETE FROM pages WHERE id_parent NOT IN (SELECT id FROM pages)
```

Assuming your parent rows have a null id_parent you'll need to add:

```
AND NOT id_parent IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM    pages pc
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    pages pp
        WHERE   pp.id = pc.id_parent
        )
```

Unlike `IN` solutions, works for rows with `id_parent` being a `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much as you would say it in English

```
Delete Pages Where parent does not exist,
```

or in SQL:

```
 Delete Pages
 Where Not Exists 
     (Select * From pages
      Where Id = p.id_Parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join for this in SQL Server. Don't know if it will work in all databases)

```
delete p
     --select *
from pages p
left join Parent pt on p.id = pt.id
where pt.id is null
```

I added the select part in the comments becasue you can run it first to see exactly what records you will be deleting.